# How to disable button column in the datagridview for selected data

Tags: datagridviewcolumn, disabled-control

```c#
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["RESER"].Index)
        {
            SelectedITEMID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnITEMID"].Value.ToString());
            string ITEMNAME = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnITEMNAME"].Value.ToString();
            string SERIALNO = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ColumnSERIALNO"].Value.ToString();

            frmSetup_RFIDItem_Update frmSRI_Update = new frmSetup_RFIDItem_Update();
            frmSRI_Update.setSelectedInfo1(SelectedITEMID, ITEMNAME, SERIALNO);
            frmSRI_Update.ShowDialog();
            frmSRI_Update.Dispose();

            getRegisteredRFIDItemList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't rely on your title to convey the entire question.  Provide a proper explanation.  Do you want to disable all buttons in the column?  Just the current row?  All rows that are selected?  Something else?

Comment: i want to disable button column for the selected data. Yes, all row that are selected. Only the enable button can open the other winform page..thank you

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to get the row that contains the clicked button because you're already doing it.  Simply test the `Selected` property of that row and only do something if it's `false`.

If you want to draw the buttons as disabled in those rows then that's something else and, I believe, would require you to create your own derived column and cell classes.   [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619.aspx) may be of interest in that case.

Comment: then, any idea to select the property of that row, to be false. only for selected row..because i already make this in 2 days and yet still not success..any idea..thank you

Comment: It's a property like any other.  If you don't know how to get the value of a property then you've got far bigger problems.  How is it that you are able to test the Index property of a column in your existing code yet for some reason you're unable to test the Selected property of a row?  Don't try to turn this into more than it is.  You know how to get a property value and compare it to something else because you're already doing it.

Comment: ok..thanks for the advice and support. i'll try 1st..thank you very much